# can't call post to asp.net page in page unload event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, server-side

I am trying to work within a legacy application that uses framesets. I am trying to fire server side code from the page unload event. Here is some example code that demonstrates the problem.

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SimpleTest._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<frameset rows="20%,80%">
    <frame name="Frame2" src="Frame2.aspx">
        <frameset>
            <frame name="Frame1" src="Frame1.aspx">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Frame2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Frame2.aspx.cs" Inherits="SimpleTest.Frame2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSecond" runat="server" Text="Button Second" onclick="btnSecond_Click" /> 
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('onbeforeunload' in window) {
        window.onbeforeunload = (function () { clearSessionData(); });
    } else {
        if ('onunload' in window) {
            window.onunload = (function () { clearSessionData(); });
        }
    }

    function clearSessionData() {
        alert("clearSessionData fired!");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Frame2.aspx/someFunction",
            success: function () { alert("SUCCESS"); },
            error: function () { alert("ERROR"); }
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Frame2.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SimpleTest
{
    public partial class Frame2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void btnSecond_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int test = 1;
            test++;
        }

        protected void someFunction()
        {
            int test = 1;
            test++;
        }
    }
}
```

I did not include the code for Frame1.aspx because that page is empty, in this example.

If I run this testing code, the alert that says "clearSessionData fired!" runs, and the alert box is displayed. But, the next line does not fire the server function "someFunction".

I have also tried using $.post() instead of $.ajax() but, have had no luck with that either. Does anyone have experience with this? Is there some problem with trying to fire server-side code from framesets using jQuery? How would you accomplish this, using jQuery or any other method? I have tried several options but, nothing seems to fire the server side code.

Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

Thanks.

ADDED COMMENT:

As a side note, if I have a simple page, with no frames, I can put code in a button's server-side click event, then create a Javascript function that uses jQuery's "trigger" method to call the button's server-side click code without any problem. See this example code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('onbeforeunload' in window) {
        window.onbeforeunload = (function () { clearSessionData(); });
    } else {
        if ('onunload' in window) {
            window.onunload = (function () { clearSessionData(); });
        }
    }

    function clearSessionData() {
        $("#Button1").trigger("click");
    }
</script>
```

This works just fine, with the click event code firing when the browser is closed (and other events that fire unload). But, for whatever reason, using frames breaks all of this.

Comment: I don't think you can call server-side functions that way. You should define it as a webmethod or so. I just found [this article](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/01/Call-Server-Side-function-from-JavaScript-in-ASP-NET.html#ByJQueryajax) that could be of use to you

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added some further explanation in my original post, about using jQuery's trigger method, which works fine in a simple page.

Comment: Can you show an example where you use the jQuery trigger method from frames where it breaks? I don't know if you are putting the trigger method inside the frame (e.g. Frame2.aspx) or on the frame container (Default.aspx).

Comment: If, in the clearSessionData function above, you replace the $.ajax() call with $("#btnSecond").trigger("click"), that is what I have been trying.

Comment: It looks like the click event of the button is being aborted before being sent to the server. I was seeing this behavior when it was not in a frame as well using IE10. See my updated answer for something that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn someFunction (on the server) into a page method. Page methods can be called from client side code through AJAX calls.

Here is an article explaining such: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Basically you decorate your method with the WebMethod and ScriptMethod attribute. Also, make it public:

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod]    
public static void someFunction()
{
    int test = 1;
    test++;
}
```

These will require using statements for System.Web.Services and System.Web.Script.Services.

**UPDATE**: I just saw your updated question saying you are using .NET 2.0. If you cannot use Page Methods, here is a workaround. First, create a Generic HttpHandler. I called mine KillSession.ashx. Note you also have to implement the marker interface **IRequiresSessionState** to be able to access the HttpSession.

KillSession.ashx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace TestFrames
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for KillSession
    /// </summary>
    public class KillSession : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Session != null)
            {
                context.Session.Clear();
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your Default.aspx (frame container) add a function called killSession. Notice it calls KillSession.ashx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SimpleTest._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function killSession() {
            console.log("Killing Session");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "KillSession.ashx",
                success: function () { alert("SUCCESS"); },
                error: function () { alert("ERROR"); }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<frameset rows="20%,80%">
    <frame name="Frame2" src="Frame2.aspx">
        <frameset>
            <frame name="Frame1" src="Frame1.aspx">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Then from your frames page (e.g. Frames2.aspx):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('onbeforeunload' in window) {
        window.onbeforeunload = (function () { clearSessionData(); });
    } else {
        if ('onunload' in window) {
            window.onunload = (function () { clearSessionData(); });
        }
    }

    function clearSessionData() {
        alert("clearSessionData fired!");
        if (typeof window.top.killSession === "function") {
            window.top.killSession();
        }
    }
</script>
```

This will call the top level frame (Default.aspx) killSession function whenever there is an unload event within the frame.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I cannot get the WebMethod declaration to help (I get the same behavior whether it is there or not). One detail I neglected to mention was that this legacy app is in .NET 2.0 so, System.Web.Script is not available to me. Thank you for your suggestions. I will continue researching. Also - I added some more information to my original post.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for your fantastic response! I was able to get that working without much trouble at all. This all works with Firefox and with IE but, I can't get it to work with Chrome except, bizarrely, when I use Chrome developer tools to put a break point in the killSession() function. If I put a break point there, then everything works. I have made the ajax call synchronous, but that has not helped (though it does help with debugging). Any thoughts on this would be appreciated. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I just tried the sample solution I made in Chrome and it works without any modifications. If you kept the console.log statement, it should be logging "Killing Session" to your console window. Also, if you watch network traffic, there should be a call to KillSession.ashx when leaving the frame. Maybe it is a caching issue? I'm thinking your just missing something simple.

Comment: Thanks again, Patrick. It must have been a caching issue, because it is working well now, as far as I can tell. I will continue testing it to make sure there isn't some weird, intermittent error but, for the moment, all looks good. I can't thank you enough for your help. I was having a really difficult time finding a solution that would work in, not only the current various browsers, but the older versions of browsers (IE) as well. Thank you, thank you, thank you.